# PHP Displaying MySQL Tables Increase Page Load Speed

Tags: php, mysql

I have written a PHP script to display MySQL tables in HTML tables. They are being displayed by a foreach statement running through an array of the table names, and then a while loop to create the rows of the table within that foreach statement.

```
<ul>
<?php foreach($tables as $table) : ?>
    <li>
        <h1><?php echo $table; ?></h1>
        <?php $result = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM db.$table"); ?>

        <table>
            <tr class="headings">
                <td>Heading 1</td>
                <td>Heading 2</td>
                <td>Heading 3</td>
                <!-- ETC -->
            </tr>

            <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) : ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $row['col1']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['col2']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['col3']; ?></td>
                    <!-- ETC -->
                </tr>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        </table>
    </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

I will be using CSS to hide all of the tables, and then show them one the table name has been clicked. However due to the number of tables that I have to display and the number of rows each has (around 150 tables some with thousands of rows, on average around 500) this is causing the page to take significant time to load.

I wanted to know if there was someway to either only load the tables once the table name has been clicked and maybe de-load it after it is hidden again, or only load tables in as the page is scrolled down.

The most effective way I can come up with would be to probably set the table name as a link and then just open a new page with only the relevant table in it, but I'm not sure how I could achieve this?

Comment: First Show Table Name. On Click, Show That Table Contents Via Ajax.

Comment: You could use Ajax with JQuery to achieve this

Comment: I'm not sure what 'table' array you are looping through or how many times you are looping through it, but try pulling your query out of the loop. Then use PHP to loop through and filter the data that you want. You are not accessing that much data, so that is not the problem, it's the number of times you access the data.